# "shell returned 2" when I try to indent

Tags: indentation

I have a server with vim installed and an empty `.vimrc`.  I open a python file and run `:set filetype=python`. I then try to indent a line with `==` and vim complains:

```
:.!indent
shell returned 2

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Then the line is replaced with

```
indent: Standard input:2: Error:Unexpected end of file
```

When I try `:help =`, the buffer says

```
E433: No tags file
E149: Sorry, no help for =
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Is there a minimum configuration needed in order for `=` to work?

Comment: See `:help =`. All information to be checked is there.

Comment: @VanLaser Thanks for the tip, though that just furthers the mystery.

Comment: You either have a vim configuration that uses `indent`, or you don't have support for internal indenting with `=` in Vim (which means, it *has* to use an external `indent` program). But, in this way, you seem to loose the ability to only indent a line (probably `indent` wants an entire file, a valid/complete text as input). Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19590619/5000478. Also, even if `.vimrc` is empty, it's still possible that a system-wide `vimrc` is used/read. Try starting vim as `vim -u ~/.vimrc` and check how `=` works (is it still relying on `indent`?).

Comment: And this is the help your vim should have displayed: http://pastebin.com/jaCTFB6k Perhaps you could install a "normal" vim version on that server?

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve your question, but at least ":help =" ought to be run.
So i suggest you reinstall vim!

Comment: Using ! before a command makes it a shell command, isn't? I think you can directly give the command without ! sign.

Answer (score 2):

The warning comes from indent. You may got same warning in command line from indent when feeding some incomplete source lines.

And check your vim's equalprg/formatprg setting if it's global or specific on certain filetype. I never tried indent on python code.

Here is my vim setting for c/cpp filetype, with indent's warning surpressed,

```
autocmd FileType c,cpp set equalprg=indent\ 2>/dev/null\ -gnu;true
```

> `2>/dev/null` surpress any warning messages from indent
>
> `;true` return 0(success) to make vim happy